# How can I make this menu to be displayed in high resolution line only?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site:

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/

Currently all menu items are displayed one above the other.
I want to be displayed in high resolution on line and when to display the menu tightens subducted

How can I do this?
I use bootstrap

This is code HTML:

```
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color:lavender;">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display --> 
  <div class="navbar-header"> 
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> 
  </div> 
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling --> 
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
    <?php /* Primary navigation */
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu' => 'top_menu',
  'depth' => 2,
  'container' => false,
  'menu_class' => 'nav',
  //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
  'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
);
?>
  </div>
</nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Erika ! no offence , thats a css job , and should't be very difficult . plus if anybody here has to help you , u'll probably have to post the generated HTML from your console on here .

Comment: if you put inline-block display appears well on large resolutions but occurs also in line and when the menu collapses...that`s my problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague depiction of what you should be doing, by default if you're following how the bootstrap navbar should be coded in HTML, you shouldn't be having the problem you're having right now.

Try this :

```
 @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
      ul li {
         display: inline-block; 
       }
    }
```